# How to connect Arduino 5v pin with multiple things?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-due

I am trying to connect a Bluetooth module and a gas sensor to Arduino.

- Bluetooth module: [HM-10](http://www.eduino.kr/product/detail.html?board_no=4&product_no=317&cate_no=58&display_group=1&keyword=)
- Gas sensor: [MQ-2](http://www.eduino.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=120&cate_no=34&display_group=1)

I read the guides for the HM-10 and MQ-2 and they both need to use the Arduino's 5v pin. I did a lot of searching but I could not find a proper example.

I would like you to give me a link to an example that uses the 5v pin for multiple modules. It would be nice if the circuit configuration was included.

Comment: > I read the guides for the HM-10 and MQ-2 and they both need to use the Arduino's 5v pin. I did a lot of searching but I could not find a proper example. do you envision it being much more complicated than wiring them, separately and individually, to the 5v pin? that's how it is normally done gazillion of times every day.

Comment: If you are trying to connect multiple things, you should first consider if it is appropriate to have their power passing through the Arduino at all.  Often it's better to give them their own routes to the power supply, and only share a common ground with the Arduino.  Additionally, the HM10 requires something like 3.3v **NOT 5v**.

Answer (score 5):

5V is just 5V. It's not a signal, it's just a voltage level. If you need to connect multiple things to it then just connect multiple things to it. If that means connecting wires together then so be it.

Yes, you can use breadboards for it, but that's pretty wasteful if all you want to do is connect a few 5V wires together. It's simpler just to strip the ends and twist them together. Maybe add some tape to insulate them so you don't get accidental short circuits.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to just use a breadboard to connect your devices to your Arduino:

[image: breadboard]

---

I can't read Chinese, so I can't check the specifications of these particular devices, but you need to be aware of the power limitations on your Arduino.

The maximum total current you can draw when the device is powered via external power supply is 1A for the [Arduino Uno](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-uno-rev3), 800mA for the [Due](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-due) and 500mA for the [Nano](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano). Check the specs for your board on the [Arduino site](https://www.arduino.cc/).

Arduino-compatible devices may vary - check the specs for the device you're usiing.

---

Note: If you're not powering your board via USB, the total 5V current limit coming out of the Arduino is limited by the voltage regulator on your particular board, and/or your input power supply (whichever provides less power).